# Adding color to bash right prompt causes unwanted behaviour

Tags: bash, colors, bashrc, prompt

```
rightprompt() {
    green=$(tput setaf 156)
    yellow=$(tput setaf 228)
    red=$(tput setaf 203)
    printf "%*s" $COLUMNS "${green}$(date +%a), ${yellow}$(date +%b\ %d), ${red}$(date +%H:%M)"
}
PS1='\[$(tput sc; rightprompt; tput rc)\]╭─\[\e[1;33m\]\u\[\e[31m\]@\[\e[32m\]\h\[\e[m\] in \[\e[1;36m\]\w\n╰─\[\e[35m\]\[\e[m\] '
```

The above code is in my `.bashrc`. I use Archlinux x86_64 and alacritty terminal emulator.

This code results in the right prompt to be shifted to the left from the edge of the terminal. Screenshot showing the shift:
[image: Right prompt significantly shifted to the left]

Other images provided for reference (each subsequent image has one color removed):
When `{red}` is removed:
[image: less shifted to the left]

When `{yellow}` is removed:
[image: even less left shift]

When `{green}` is removed:
[image: no left shift]

There is no shift when no colors are added so those color variables are the problem. Each `tput setaf` somehow messes with the `$COLUMNS` or `%*s` in some way and I don't know what to do.

Comment: My first comment was not really helpful, sorry. Now I think the real culprit is `printf` [that counts bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350243/108618). In my Kubuntu `tput setaf 156 | wc -c` prints `11`, this means it generates 11 bytes. They are unprintable. Other "colors" generate 11 bytes each as well. `printf` generates a string that would reach the end of the screen if all bytes were printable sinlge-byte characters. 33 are unprintable. `"$((COLUMNS+33))"` instead of `$COLUMNS` is a basic fix. In general (depending on locale) `date …` may generate multi-byte characters and then…

Comment: … and then `printf` will err even more. It may be no fixed addend will be right (e.g. there may be locale where on Tuesday `33` is right, but on Wednesday one needs `34`). I'm not posting an answer because what I have so far is not perfect and I suspect there may be other issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep an eye out for other methods of doing a right-justified bash prompt. I'll see throughout the week if anything changes due to locale change.